# How do I reduce usb mouse wake up sensitivity?

Tags: usb, suspend, mouse, wakeup

Ubuntu by default can wake up by any tiny little movement of the mouse. Even 1 millimetre of mouse movement makes my system wake up. So there are many situations when the system wakes up by accident.

**I know it is possible to disable it completely but I am curious to know, is there any way to reduce its sensitivity instead of disabling that?**

In windows even when this feature is on, waking up the system by mouse movement needs a significant movement of  the mouse. You need to move mouse for example 2 inches or in two different ways to make the system wake up.